# Error on retrieving email by name when email name have brackets

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I`m trying to retrieve emails by name using .NET API client but when the email have brackets in name the api doesnt find the object.

This is my code:

```
        string requestID;

        // Filter by TaskResultID (the unique id for the import)  
        SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
        sfp.Property = "Name";
        sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
        sfp.Value = new string[] { "wednesday - 20140319 - Clients [nws]" };


        // Create the RetrieveRequest  
        RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
        request.ObjectType = "Email";
        request.Filter = sfp;
        request.Properties = new string[] { "ObjectID", "CustomerKey", "Name" };

        // Execute the RetrieveRequest  
        APIObject[] results;
        string status = ETclient.Retrieve(request, out requestID, out results);

        return results[0] as Email; (ERROR HERE!)
```

Does anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are either of these answers helpful?  Hoping to get this question marked answered for you - please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is probably to do String.replace(find, replace) for each bracket. This problem is likely due to the way regex handles square brackets.

Comment: Hummm... I`ve tried so but the API still not finding the object

Answer (score 0):

I think the original assumption of the bracket causing issues in the REGEX is the case here.  Try escaping the string literals like this:

```
sfp.Value = new string[] { "wednesday - 20140319 - Clients \U007Bnws\U007D" };
```

Based on what I am reading, this seems like it's a possible issue.